# Based on the data I have, what is the most correct way to calculate variance?

Tags: variance, python, standard-deviation

I am currently extracting (scraping) data **from a web page**, the conclusive data I receive comes from a time serie but I don't have access to the data inside it, so I don't really know the weight of the variables (outputs) I get, but I have some important data.

**Minimum Price**, example 5.00

**Maximum Price**, example 12.00

**Average Price**, example 11.00

**Current Price**, example 9.50

Is there a way I can have a good approximation of the variance or standard deviation?

**I'm programming in Python but I'm ok with a mathematical solution**

Comment: Do you not have the individual observations?

Comment: No, only an image (literally) of the timeline is available, but it doesn't give you internal data

Comment: So you can extract the information listed but not the raw data, or is Current Price the raw data? You want to understand if you can use a time series of these descriptive statistics to calculate the variance? Do you get a Current Price for every possible time point that contributes to the others? Or do you get intermittent Current Prices? Do the windows for Min, Max and Ave overlap or are they separated in time?

Comment: I have access to Minimum Price (historic), Maximum Price (historic), Average Price (historic), Current Price. That is the only data. The timeline is a plain picture and the only data really have is contained in those 4 variables.
I only get current price today, no other points

Comment: If the graph has axes labelled, you could probably estimate the data points themselves from the pixel locations of the drawn timeline relative to the axes. This won't be very accurate but could probably give you a decent estimate.